# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"А хамам тут еда положена(,) или как?"

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, что заставили думать над предложением. Правлю ответ. Утро вечера оказалось мудренее ))).
Союз "или" соединяет, по-моему, два простых предложения.  Второе неполное. Ср.  А хамам тут еда положена или как (здесь положено, принято)? Запятая, я думаю, ***не нужна***, так как объединяющим средством здесь служит интонация. 
Нашла у Лопатина:
Запятая между частями ССП не ставится, если  [части сложносочиненного предложения представляют собой побудительные, вопросительные или восклицательные предложения; объединяющей здесь оказывается интонация, а в побудительных предложениях могут быть и общие частицы: Где будет собрание и кто его председатель? — общая вопросительная интонация].

Comment: А разве "еда" не подлежащее при сказуемом "положена" ?

Comment: Да и в вопросительных предложениях запятая между двумя простыми предложениями не ставится. Так ведь?

Comment: Конечно, Вы правы. В первом предложении основа "еда положена", во втором основы нет, предложение неполное. И запятая не ставится в ССП, если части ССП объединяет вопросительная интонация. Спасибо!Засыпала и просыпалась с мыслями о Вашем предложении...